# How to navigate via clickHandlers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning React and I'm stuck in the following scenario.

There is an input field and on clicking the search button it takes the input value and redirect to /search/search-query/some-action

I have setup the path, defined the route to the correct view. And, I was able to do hit this path using href links. But my actual requirement is to have a button and take user to this path via onClick handler.

Searched a lot and found multiple (vague) solutions like, react-navigate-mixin etc. But I couldnt find any documentation around its usages.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm gonna make the assumption that you're not building a single page app and using something along the lines of React router. And that what you need to do is simply navigate to a url based on the input.

There are two main ways of doing depending on wether you want to:

1. Style an `<a>` as your button:

```js
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() { return {query: ''} },
  queryChange: function(evt) {
    this.setState({query: evt.target.value});
  },
  _buildLinkHref: function() {
    return '/search/'+this.state.query+'/some-action';
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="component-wrapper">
        <input type="text" value={this.state.query} />
        <a href={this._buildLinkHref()} className="button">
          Search
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This way you're keeping the query (value of the input) in the state. And whenever the input changes is automatically changes the href of the link.

2. Use a `<button>` and redirect programatically:

```js
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() { return {query: ''} },
  queryChange: function(evt) {
    this.setState({query: evt.target.value});
  },
  handleSearch: function() {
    window.location = '/search/'+this.state.query+'/some-action';
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="component-wrapper">
        <input type="text" value={this.state.query} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSearch()} className="button">
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This way you handle the redirect programatically by setting your desired location to `window.location`.

Comment: It reloads the entire application. What if I don't want to reload the page and just want to see the results without reload?

Comment: @GauravPaliwal I'd recommend looking into https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Answer (score 2):

Adding on from the existing answer may need to bind your function like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
}
```