# Linking button to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I currently have a button

```
class Button extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                onPress= #I need this to return the second page of my app
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Next Page</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

What should I do to link this button to the second page of my app? Assuming I have already imported the page.

```
import SecondPage from './SecondPage'
```

Comment: onpress of the button you want to go to second page? or you want to make the second page as the part of this button ? which version of router you are using ?

Comment: Are you using `react-router` 4? Give us more information.

Comment: @dogui I've not heard of react router 4 until now, I'm currently coding on react-native. I want the button to direct the user to another page in the app that I have imported

Answer (score 28):

Below example can fix all your issues :

- React Router Navigation
- Browser Refresh Issue.
- Browser Back Button Issue.

Please make sure you have installed `react-router-dom`

If not installed. Use this command to install `npm i react-router-dom`

***index.js***

```
   import React from "react";
   import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
   import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

   import Page1 from "./Page1";
   import Page2 from "./Page2";

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Page1} />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>,
      rootElement
    );
```

***Page1.js***

```
   import React from "react";
   import {Link } from "react-router-dom";

    function Page1() {

        return (
          <div>
            <p>
              This is the first page.
              <br />
              Click on the button below.
            </p>
            <Link to="/page2"><button>
              Go to Page 2 
            </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        );

    }

    export default Page1;
```

***Page2.js***

```
   import React from "react";

   function Page2() {

        return (
          <div>
            <p>This is the second page.</p>
          </div>
        );

    }

    export default Page2;
```

Answer (score 9):

use `<Link>` from `react-router`

```
<Link to ='/href' ></Link>
```

Comment: im not sure where i should put this. Is it under the view tag like this: <Link to ='/SecondPage'></Link>

Comment: "Uncaught Error: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>"

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this. Details below

**Option 1: If you are using react router**, you could use Link to redirect users to the second page.

Declare a route in your router config to go to the second page and use . More details here
http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

**Option 2: If you are not using react router and just redirecting**, use the onClick on the button to redirect to a new URL. E.g. [React: How to navigate via clickHandlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250103/react-how-to-navigate-via-clickhandlers)

Note- Option 2 is a dirty way of navigating from one page to other. A sophisticated way will be to use react-router. You will need it when your app grows big and there are many redirects happening on the page.

Hope that helps!

Comment: For option 1, do I do it like this under the <View> tag? <Link to ='/SecondPage'></Link>

Comment: I would say do it before the <View> tag